# Using Articles in a Simple List

Tags: articles, lists

An abstract noun is something that doesn't physically exist, such as an idea, concept, quality, emotion or event.

OR

An abstract noun is something that doesn't physically exist, such as an idea, a concept, a quality, an emotion or an event.

Thanks.

Comment: Both versions are fine. It's common to assume the presence of an omitted word—as in the first sentence..

Comment: I was having one of those moments where something really basic suddenly seemed problematic. I think you're right about the article being omitted though.

Cheers!